# Default WP search excluding specific characters, is it possible?

Tags: search, exclude, customization

I would like to know if it possible to customize the default search module of Wordpress.
I've a website dealing with teams and teams' news.

Some of those teams has their names written like this

- H.M.S.
- L.A. Dream
- N.Y. Invaders

I would like that the search modules could be able to manage those teams in the results even if i look for strings like **HMS**, or **LA Dream**, or **NY**, instead of filling the characters with dots. Does anybody has some suggestion, or know a WP trick that at the moment i'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Search Terms Dotifier:

Here's one idea using the `request` filter to append "dotted" words of two or three characters that don't contain any dots, to the current search terms.

So if your search string is for example:

> The LA Dreams

it will become:

> The LA Dreams L.A.

Here's a demo plugin to modify the default search:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Search Terms Dotifier
 * Author:      birgire
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/157972/26350
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

add_filter( 'request', function( $request ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && isset( $request['s'] ) )
    {
        // Dont' dotify these words (lower case):
        $exclude = array( 'the', 'in', 'it', 'he', 'she', 'was' );

        // Loop over search terms:
        $words = explode( ' ', $request['s'] );
        foreach( (array) $words as $word )
        {
             // Words with two or three chars that don't contain any dots:
             if( mb_strlen( $word ) > 1
                 && mb_strlen( $word ) < 4 
                 && false === strpos( $word, '.' ) 
                 && ! in_array( mb_strtolower( $word ), $exclude, true ) 
             )
             {
                 // Append the 'dotted' word:
                 $words[] = join( '.', str_split( $word ) ) . '.';
             }
         }
         $request['s'] = join( ' ', $words );
    }
    return $request;
});
```

You can hopefully extend this further to your needs.

Comment: it works fine, great solution